# Python Dictionary/Loop Output

Tags: python

- Make a dictionary for nine Tampa Bay Rays that are given. Use the
  player names as keys and a list for each value.
- Each value list should hold the position played by the player, the
  batting order, and current batting average. See above.
- When the dictionary is complete, use a for loop to display the
  dictionary keys and values. This is what I got for this
- Next, use loop(s) to print the "lineup" (the dictionary in batting
  order). **This is the step I need some help with, not sure how I go
  about doing an order for a dictionary like so. A list made more sense
  to me but that is not the question.**

  ```
    main():
        rays_players = { 'DeJesus': ['DH', 6, 299],
                   'Loney': ['1B', 4, 222],
                   'Rivera': ['C', 9, 194],
                   'Forsythe': ['2B', 5, 304],
                   'Souza Jr': ['RF', 2, 229],
                   'Longoria': ['3B', 3, 282],
                   'Cabrera': ['SS', 7, 214],
                   'Kiermaier': ['CF', 1, 240],
                   'Guyer': ['LF', 8, 274] }

      for key in rays_players:
          print(key, rays_players[key])
     main()
  ```

**This is what I have been trying, but it is not working, I am very new at this:**

```
for key in sorted(rays_players.items(), key=lambda v: (v)):
    print ("%s: %s" % (key))
```

**Step 4 is supposed to look like this:**

Batting 1: CF Kiermaier, current avg: 240

Batting 2: RF Souza Jr, current avg: 229

Batting 3: 3B Longoria, current avg: 282

Batting 4: 1B Loney, current avg: 222

Batting 5: 2B Forsythe, current avg: 304

Batting 6: DH DeJesus, current avg: 299

Batting 7: SS Cabrera, current avg: 214

Batting 8: LF Guyer, current avg: 274

Batting 9: C Rivera, current avg: 194

Comment: what do you mean by "bating order"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```
rays_players = {'DeJesus': ['DH', 6, 299],
                'Loney': ['1B', 4, 222],
                'Rivera': ['C', 9, 194],
                'Forsythe': ['2B', 5, 304],
                'Souza Jr': ['RF', 2, 229],
                'Longoria': ['3B', 3, 282],
                'Cabrera': ['SS', 7, 214],
                'Kiermaier': ['CF', 1, 240],
                'Guyer': ['LF', 8, 274]}

for key, value in sorted(rays_players.items(), key=lambda v: v[1][1]):
    print("Batting {}: {} {}, current avg: {}".format(value[1], value[0], key, value[2]))
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I am happy I at least had some of the same words in the code I tried xD